# multiple ajax calls with jquery deferred - is there a way to not reject if one call fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

Hi I'm doing multiple ajax calls and would like to combine the results 
I'm using following code:

```
    var args = [
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/200/2",
    type:"get",
    dataType:"jsonp"
}),
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/200/1",
    type:"get",
    dataType:"jsonp"
})
    ];


    jQuery.when.apply(this, args)
    .done(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var singleResult = arguments[i]; 
                console.log("always");
                console.log(singleResult);
                                    //here code to combine results
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var singleResult = arguments[i]; 
                console.log("fail");
                console.log(singleResult);
        }
    });
```

It works perfectly fine when both calls return 200 status code
but in the current system sometimes one off the calls might return 500 or 404
When this happens the whole promise is rejected and done is newer called 
I know that this is the default behaviour - when one call fail the whole thing fail

Question: Is there an easy way to make it work this way that single failure will not cause the whole thing to fail
In other words Lets say I fired 10 calls, 7 succeeded  3 failed
I would like that the done is called with these 7 results, and fail with 3 results

Comment: How about "when then" instead of "when done"? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: It does not matter which one you will use, the problem is that default behaviour of when is that 
**In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when, the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected** So as soon as one call fail the whole thing fails - I'm thinking of implementing my own version of when which will keep all res.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solve it by taking the  "when" implementation and creating my own version 
Here it is

```
    $.extend({
when2: function( subordinate /* , ..., subordinateN */ ) {
    var i = 0,
        resolveValues = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ),
        length = resolveValues.length,

        // the count of uncompleted subordinates
        remaining = length !== 1 || ( subordinate && jQuery.isFunction( subordinate.promise ) ) ? length : 0,

        // the master Deferred. If resolveValues consist of only a single Deferred, just use that.
        deferred = remaining === 1 ? subordinate : jQuery.Deferred(),

        // Update function for both resolve and progress values
        updateFunc = function( i, contexts, values ) {
            return function( value ) {
                contexts[ i ] = this;
                values[ i ] = arguments.length > 1 ? Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) : value;
                if( values === progressValues ) {
                    deferred.notifyWith( contexts, values );
                } else if ( !( --remaining ) ) {
                    deferred.resolveWith( contexts, values );
                }
            };
        },

        progressValues, progressContexts, resolveContexts;

    // add listeners to Deferred subordinates; treat others as resolved
    if ( length > 1 ) {
        progressValues = new Array( length );
        progressContexts = new Array( length );
        resolveContexts = new Array( length );
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            if ( resolveValues[ i ] && jQuery.isFunction( resolveValues[ i ].promise ) ) {
                resolveValues[ i ].promise()
                    .done( updateFunc( i, resolveContexts, resolveValues ) )
                    //.fail( deferred.reject )
                    // here is the modified line
                    .fail( updateFunc( i, resolveContexts, resolveValues ) )
                    .progress( updateFunc( i, progressContexts, progressValues ) );
            } else {
                --remaining;
            }
        }
    }

    // if we're not waiting on anything, resolve the master
    if ( !remaining ) {
        deferred.resolveWith( resolveContexts, resolveValues );
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
    });



    jQuery.when2.apply(this, args)
         .then(function(){
            var combinedResults = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var singleResult = arguments[i]; 
                console.log(singleResult);
                if(singleResult[1]==="success"){
                    for(var serviceName in singleResult[0]){
                        combinedResults[serviceName] = singleResult[0][serviceName];
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(combinedResults);
        });
```

});

In this way when will always finish with all the results 
Arguments passed to then are Arrays 
each contain tree values where second one is the status by which you can determine that call succeeded or failed

I've placed my test code on github, it has a little nodejs server which returns different http status codes for test purposes.

https://github.com/szydan/test-jquery-deffered

Comment: This can't really work, as the deferred you return can only be *either* in solved *or* in rejected state

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to handle your promises manually to always resolve, only sometimes with an error object or message. Something like

```
var deferreds = [];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  deferreds.push(defer)
  $.ajax(/* options */)
  .then(function(res) {
    defer.resolve(res);
  }, function(err) {
    defer.resolve(err);
  })
}

$.when(deferreds)
.then(function() {
  var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // do something with results
});
```